# Windows 7 Explorer clearing history

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, favorites

So i have alot(more than on screenshot) of "Favorites" in pop up menu of explorer (right click on explorer icon on taskbar) [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QipmW.jpg)

Also i am using "Most visited" (i think on english it is)
But sometimes windows just clearing this! It saves all history of browsing and favorites everywhere except for pop up menu!

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Any disk cleanup/maintenance software?

Comment: Nothing like this man. I thought it could be comething like CCleaner but i dont have programms like this

Comment: There isn't much to go on here.